# Where can I find the complete schemas for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 project files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, xsd

The only thing I could find so far were those two pages

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y4sy8216(v=vs.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y4sy8216(v=vs.90).aspx

Along with the respective "descriptions".

However, they are far from complete as is evidenced by the missing descriptions for elements underneath the `Tool` element.

So then I found the descriptions for `VCProjectEngine` in the VS installation folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.xml
```

but it's unclear whether the names of the object properties is a 1:1 mapping to those inside the resulting `.vcproj` file?

Things appear to be a little more straightforward for newer VS versions (MSBuild based), but not completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are none that describe the whole project file. The thing is that many tags work by convention, many tasks can be declared and named inline by simply calling out to the task assembly.

So even though for the basic structure a XSD exists, there is none that describes every possible way a project file can be setup not can you validate the project file without loading the tasks and have them validate their own snippets.

Comment: Thanks, that's of course disconcerting news, but alright. Which raises an interesting question for me, though. Shouldn't it be possible well-formed XML to always have a complete schema?

Comment: Yes, but the valid schema would probably contain a lot of `xs:Any`'s in it, making it less than helpful. It's basically what is shipping with Visual Studio. Those parts that are well known have a schema, the parts where you can extend allow just about anything.